# ElasticSearch match query score

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Using standard analyzer I have a following query

```
{
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "title": {
                    "query": "iphone 6",
                    "operator": "and"
                }
            }
        },
        "track_scores": True,
        "sort": [
            {
                "_score": {
                    "order": "desc"
                }
            }
        ],
        "size": 10
    }
```

which gives me following results 'title' => 'score'

```
iPhone 6 Plus 64GB  => 14.105422
iPhone 6 Plus 128GB => 13.942985
iPhone 6 16GB       => 13.678013
iPhone 6 64GB       => 13.473294
iPhone 6 Plus 16GB  => 12.974828
iPhone 6 128GB      => 12.974828
```

Why is `iPhone 6 Plus` higher than `iPhone 6` and what should I do to get one of the `iPhone 6` as first one?

Comment: can you update with your mapping please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working using groovy

```
{
        "query": {
            "function_score": {
                "score_mode": "sum",
                "boost_mode": "replace",
                "query": {
                    "match": {
                        "title": {
                            "query":  "iphone 6",
                            "operator": "and"
                        }
                    }
                },

                "functions": [{
                    "script_score": {
                        "script": "def score = 1000 - _source.title.size(); score",
                        "lang": "groovy"
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        "track_scores": True,
        "sort": [
            {
                "_score": {
                    "order": "desc"
                }
            }
        ],
        "size": 1
    }
```